# Wordpress: category collection with "&orderby=date&order=asc" but order refuses to ascend

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Here is some code I am trying to use from [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-the-posts-of-one-category-in-a-page-solved) topic :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().
'&order=ASC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=10'.'&post_status=publish,future');?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p><?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

By the time the post loads, is it too late to use "orderby"? Is that why it stubbornly stays "newest post first"?

Answer (score 0):

Try orderby first and order second.

```
&orderby=date&order=ASC
```

Comment: I wish that changed something! It apparently has not ... Thanks for the idea.

Comment: have you tried using WP_Query in place of query_posts? I find it actually works many times when query_posts doesn't and it is far more robust. Also, get_the_title doesn't print the title unless there is an echo before it. Try just the_title() in your params?

Comment: You're definitely right! WP_Query works better.`<?php
    $featuredPosts = new WP_Query();    
    $featuredPosts->query('category_name='.get_the_title().'&showposts=5&orderby=date&order=asc'); 
    while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <font class="copse" size="6"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></font>
   <!--<div class="meta">-->
   <!--By <?php the_author() ?>-->
   <!--</div>-->
    <div class="storycontent">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with everything!